# using samples in blender cycles render layer tab

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers, layers

I recently ran into the samples in the blender cycles layer tab (see picture). Somewhere I read I could change the sample rate for a specific layer. This can be useful if one layer doesn't need as many sample rates as others.

Does someone know how to use this? Would be awesome.

Regards

[image: blender cycles layer samples]

Answer (score 5):

As indicated by the tooltip when hovering the mouse pointer over it, the Render Layer Samples setting allows you to override the Number of samples used. Setting it to 0 (the default) tells Blender to use whatever is the default for the scene (ie, the number of samples set in the Samples panel of the Render properties). Setting it to a non-zero value will use that number of samples for that render layer.

Eg, setting it to ‘1’ will render that layer as if the Render Samples is set to 1.